# Error while using Meleze.Web - 1.0.0 of Nuget Gallery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nuget-package

I am trying to use [Meleze.Web - 1.0.0](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Meleze.Web) to minify the razor views of asp.net mvc 3 application. I have installed the package and modified the config as in [ReadMe](https://github.com/meleze/Meleze.Web/blob/master/README) section but it throws the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not locate Razor Host Factory type: Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory,Meleze.Web.Razor
```

The Changes i did in `~/Views/Web.config`:

```
<!--<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />-->
<host factoryType="Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory,Meleze.Web.Razor" />
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly you have downloaded with the NuGet package is called `Meleze.Web`, not `Meleze.Web.Razor` as shown in the [README](https://github.com/meleze/Meleze.Web/blob/master/README) file, so:

```
<host factoryType="Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory, Meleze.Web" />
```

You could contact the author of the package to update his README file if you want.

Comment: I have the same problem!
I installed via Nuget, I made the change in the Web.config but nothing happens.